# JavaScript timer to disable function

Tags: javascript, timer, onclick

I have a form where the submit button triggers a function. Let's call it `ycClick()`. I need this function to be disabled for 30 seconds after submit but I need the submit button to continue to work. I do not want want to disable the entire button, just the function it triggers. (If the user hits the button again before 30 seconds I need it to submit again, but not execute `ycClick()` a second time.) I've tried a million different things but to no avail. Finally I feel like I'm getting close, but for some reason it's still not working. When I click on it ycClick() isn't executing at all. What am I doing wrong? Here's what I got:

```
function ycClick(){
    ...
}



function toggleSubmit() {
    if (document.getElementById('ycsubmit').onclick == null) {
        document.getElementById('ycsubmit').onclick = ycClick();
    } else {
        document.getElementById('ycsubmit').onclick = null;
    } 
} 


function timer()
{

  if (count <= 0 || count == null)
  {
  ycClick();
  } else {
  count=30;
  counter=setInterval("timer()",1000);
  count=count-1;
 toggleSubmit();
}
}

<FORM ID="myform">
    <INPUT ID="ycsubmit" TYPE="SUBMIT" ONCLICK="timer();">
</FORM>
```

Comment: How exactly is it not working? Be specific.

Comment: @CBredlow, please don't "fix" code in questions. That may have been the actual problem. Gordie: you've given your input element the ID "mysubmit", but you're referring to it as "ycsubmit".

Comment: I didn't change code, i removed the caps.

Comment: Oh crud, you're right. It appears like I changed it in my revision, but it's actually another instance of [this problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45478/question-history-attributed-changes-to-me-that-i-didnt-make), triggered by an OP edit five minutes or less after the question's originally asked. Sorry to cast aspersions, @CBredlow.

Comment: No problem, I'll go a bit more detailed in changes.

Comment: I'm sorry I just fixed a few obvious flaws from when I changed the ID and didn't change the code, etc, as well as updated the questio to be more specific like Michael Petrotta asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should toggle the button:

```
var isEnabled = true;

function toggleSubmit() {
    if (isEnabled) {
        document.getElementById("ycsubmit").onclick = function() {};
    } else {
        document.getElementById("ycsubmit").onclick = ycClick;
    } 

    isEnabled = !isEnabled;
}
```

Also, when you used `setInterval` you don't need the parentheses or quotes for `timer`, like so:

```
counter=setInterval(timer,1000);
```

And better yet, if you want to wait 30 seconds, just toggle the button's functionality, and then 30 seconds later do it again.

```
toggleSubmit();
setTimeout(toggleSubmit(), 30000);
```

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on Incompl's answer:

when setting a timeout's function, it uses the value that you supply. Technically, your `setTimeout("timer()",1000);` will do exactly what you want.

The timeout will evaluate the "timer()", in a similar way that the [Eval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp) function works.

However, doing something such as `setTimeout(toggleSubmit(), 30000);` will produce unintended results if you are uninformed/inexperienced. The timeout must get the value for what ever you provide, and in this case, the timeout will call the toggleSubmit() function expecting it to return a value (which it doesn't). So, we end up just calling the function twice and the timeout doesn't have a function to trigger.

In order to rectify this, you must refrain from including the "()" after the name of the function. When you do this, it acts as a variable, and its value is the actual code inside of the function.

This sets you up nicely for another feature of the `setTimeout()` function. `setTimeout(toggleSubmit, 30000, "hello there", "sir");` will call the `toggleSubmit()` function and will supply the parameters "hello there" and "sir". The function doesn't actually take any parameters, so it won't do anything with them, but it is a good thing to know.